# Copy cells based on identifier in column A from a large set of data

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a large set of data in columns A:J. If there is a number 1 in column A, I need a macro to copy Columns B:J and paste it in Sheet2 under the last entry in column B.

I've written several macros to do this, but they have all taken a long time to run and are pretty inefficient due to looping through every row of data to check it for the identifier in column A.

Is there an efficient way of doing this without the whole code looping through all 9,000 rows of data?

The 1's will probably only appear in the first 2,500 (max) rows, but this amount will be variable on a monthly basis.

The 1's will always be next to each other - that is to say, once it has searched down column A to find a 1 - all other occurrences will be 1's until it changes to 2's. There will be no gaps either. TIA

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your code? Maybe someone will be able to make it quicker.

Comment: So effectively, all cells in column A contain either a `1` or a `2` and your table is sorted lowest to highest based on column A and you only need to copy the rows with a `1`.  Is your data formatted as a table (ListObject) and if so, what is the name of the table?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty instant, I set up my example for 16,000 rows and it was very fast. I am assuming row1 has headers.

```
Sub GetIt()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, rng As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("B2:J" & LstRw)
        .Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1"
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues
        .AutoFilterMode = 0
        Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I've loaded all data in sheet1 in a two dimensional array and then checked the first element `(x, 1)` of the array, if the value of this element is `1` then the elements `(x, 2)` to `(x, 10)` are copied to a second array which collects all results. Once all rows are checked, the second array is added to the table on the second sheet in one go. The results are:

> 100.000 rows have been checked in 1,08 seconds, 49.960 rows have been copied to Sheet2.

Out of curiosity I checked with the maximum number of rows of data that Excel allows the results are:

> 1.048.574 rows have been checked in 8,05 seconds, 524.340 rows have been copied to Sheet2.

Assumptions

- 2 Worksheets
- Destination is formatted as a table (listobject)

I might add that there are solutions which are shorter easier.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyData()
    Dim wsDat As Worksheet, wsDes As Worksheet
    Dim tblDes As ListObject
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arrDat() As Variant, arrDes() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long, nextRow As Long
    Dim rngDes As Range

    Set wsDat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)  'Change the numbers 1 and 2 to the names of the actual sheets and tables
    Set wsDes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Set tblDes = wsDes.ListObjects(1)

    With wsDat
        lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        arrDat = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(arrDat, 1)
        If arrDat(i, 1) = 1 Then
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim arrDes(1 To j, 1 To lastColumn - 1)

    k = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrDat, 1)
        If arrDat(i, 1) = 1 Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(arrDes, 2)
                arrDes(k, j) = arrDat(i, j + 1)
            Next j
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i

    With wsDes
        tblDes.ListRows.Add
        nextRow = tblDes.ListRows.Count
        Set rngDes = tblDes.DataBodyRange(nextRow, 2)
        Set rngDes = rngDes.Resize(UBound(arrDes, 1), UBound(arrDes, 2))
        rngDes.Value = arrDes
    End With

End Sub
```